# Is css translateZ not available in React? Unknown function 'translateZ'

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to create a parallax effect for an image on my webpage built with react. At the moment, I am using javascript however this is not an ideal solution considering 3 lines of css can do the same thing. The problem is, I need to be able to use translateZ.

When I apply `transform: translateZ(-10px);` to my image, nothing happens, and IntelliJ gives me red squiggles saying `Unknown function 'translateZ'`. Everything else is set up correctly for sure, the image is inside a wrapper div with `perspective: 10px; transform-style: preserve-3d;`, and either way this would not affect whether the function translateZ itself is recognized. These CSS properties are in a dedicated CSS file and are being applied via className, in case that helps.

I cannot for the life of me find anything about this online, which to me seems to indicate that perhaps something is messed up locally? Because I don't understand why an entire CSS function would just be absent in react for no reason.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, translate3d() also has the same issue, it is not recognized.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `translate3d(0, 0, VALUE)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, that function is also unfortunately facing the same issue for me, it is unrecognized.